# How can I display a lot of app icons on a desktop in a UI friendly way?

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, icons

Imagine I have 100 icons, 200 icons...
It is kind of the same problem Apple addressed with the dock
How can I best display them and are there any existing tools/libraries for doing so?